# retrieve firestore collection, document using angular4

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firebase database and trying to retrieve same via angular.
was able to connect to the database, however, not able to read the data... this is what I did and unable to get the data...

I am surely missing something, could any one please guide or provide a link ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserProfiles>;
  items: Observable<UserProfiles[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<UserProfiles>('UserProfiles');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }

}

export class UserProfiles{
  id?: string;
  active?: string;
  company?: string;
  email?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  password?: string;
  userId?: string;
  userType?: string;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with how you are specifically using `items`. Are you using it in your template? If you plan to only use the result of `items` in this component, just like most observables, you need to `subscribe()` to it. `this.items.subscribe(data => console.log(data))` in this component or something like `*ngFor="let item of items | async"`. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to `subscribe()` against the `Observable<UserProfiles[]>;` created by `valueChanges()()`, in this case the `items` class property, to retrieve/use the data:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserProfiles>;
  items: Observable<UserProfiles[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<UserProfiles>('UserProfiles');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
    this.items.subscribe(data => console.log(data)); // subscribe and log emitted data
  }

}
```

Otherwise, ff you are using `items` in the template, as one option you can utilize the `async` pipe to subscribe to the `items` observable and render the data:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item.someProperty}}</li>
</ul>
```